# c++ allegro 5 visual studio exception on allegro-5.0.10-monolith-md-debug.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, allegro

I have a problem with allegro that putting `allegro-5.0.10-monolith-md-debug.dll` in linker input additional dependencies causes an exception, as can be seen in the screenshot.[image]

I'm using visual stdio 2013 express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out i was installing and initializing addons before calling allegro_init()